# Adding new site in existing Sitecore 9.3 hosting platform

Tags: solution-architecture

Current Sitecore environment running 3 sites with multi-site set up approach. This is Sitecore 9.3 XP set up on Azure IaaS.

**Current XP set up:** 1 CM, 2 CD, 1 SQL Cluster for Sitecore DBs, 1 xDB SQL Cluster for xDB, 3 SolR Servers

**SQL Cluster(A) contains CM, CD DBs:** core, security, master, web, experienceforms , exm

**xDB SQL Cluster(B) contains xDBs:** messaging, referencedata, reporting, reporting_secondary

Now we need to add new main site and for that we're going to add 2 CDs from where new site will run and  backend will be new SQL Cluster(**C**) which will be copy of SQL Cluster(**A**). We'll set up replication to keep SQL Cluster(**A**) and SQL Cluster(**C**) database in sync. We'll set up new publishing target which will move new main site related content to new SQL Cluster(C).  Deployment package( code ) will be same on CM and CD servers. Request to new CDs for main site will be handled via Azure App Gateway. The reason we came up with 2 CD + SQL Cluster(**C**) is because during DR scenario , we'll bring these servers( `2 new CDs and new SQL Cluster(C)`) first since this is main site.

Can we go with addition of new CD and SQL cluster for new main site or there will be some challenges? Does this set up support A/B Testing, Content Testing, Personalization etc.

Comment: Hi Mark, Is it the same codebase for all sites? - if no, can you explain more how do you manage your releases and deployment?

Comment: @HanyShehata Yes code base is same for all 3 live sites which is on helix pattern and single deployment package is being moved to CM & CD currently. For new main site we're planning to maintain separate repo/code.

Comment: @Mark, If the new main site has brand new code, may I ask for which reasons are you planning to mirror SQL Cluster? - as per my understanding the new code will be deployed on CDs only, but will be shared with other sites on CM and databases .. please confirm if my understanding is correct

Comment: @HanyShehata New SQL Cluster(C) will be having all databases as mentioned in question but as we know `core` DB is common in CM/CD XP set up , that's why we're going to set up replication for specially  `core`  DB between SQL Cluster(C) and SQL Cluster(D). New code will be deployed on both CM and new 2 CDs. 2 new CDs will have connections to only SQL Cluster(C). Content Author team want to review pages on cms site( https://cms.mycompany.com ) before publishing.

Answer (score 0):

[@Sukhjeevan](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/1349/sukhjeevan), There're many assumptions here. although, answering your question directly, I can't see a problem with your suggested setup; however, I can suggest some changes that might simplify and save some money ;)

---

The suggested changes:

- **SQL Cluster (A)** - This is the Live cluster that will be responsible for real live traffic. This cluster should host required DBs by CD server only including your new main site - more details about the list of DBs can be found here - https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/content-delivery--cd-.html
- **SQL Cluster (B)** - This cluster will be responsible for non-live DBs (XP & CM) - more details can be found here https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/content-management--cm-.html
- Given that you are using the same codebase for all sites, I suggest to use the same CDs for all sites including the new main site, and add more servers when required and depends on traffic, ext...
- Adding a new target for your main website is a good idea; however, Sitecore can perfectly manage and handle multi-sites in one web db - this is your decision based on many factors, ex. website traffic - I've a production instance with 62 public website served by 1 web database

---

What did you get from these changes? what are the benefits?

- Your websites are up and running without any dependency on XP or CM work
- In case of issues on CM or XP, you will be losing only analytical data
- Simplify SQL cluster setup
- Straight-forward deployment
- Simplify your release management/cycle
- Less operation/maintenance headache

Hope I could help you here .. best of luck.

Comment: Yes this approach is just adding a new site in current live XP 9.3 environment without any addition in Infra side but how about during DR in this approach? Bringing main site back during DR  is also our top most priority, other sites can wait. That's why we're planning to add 2 CD and new SQL Cluster(C) so that we can bring main site back first.

Comment: You just need introduce content freeze period while running DR test; This will allow you to move DBs in secure way from content point of view